# Using eval to run a set of closures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, eval

I want to store into an array, a set of closures to be run when it been called.

Is eval the best thing to do it?

Comment: what would be called? the array?!

Comment: Using `eval` is never a good thing.

Comment: How exactly would you use eval for this?  A closure in JS retains the scope it had when the closure was made, so you should not need eval.

Comment: Why would you need eval? why not `array[0] = (function(some,closure,vars){ return function(){ return some + 'whatever';};}(1,2,3));`

Comment: @ThiefMaster Without `eval` we wouldn’t have JSON in the browser... https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L471

Comment: @David: We would - in all non-legacy browsers.

Comment: Marc, did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 2):

"Eval is evil" ;-)

but here's a possible solution

```
Array.prototype.execute = function() {
    for ( var i in this ) {
        if ( i && 'execute' != i && Function == this[ i ].constructor ) {
            this[ i ].apply( this );
        }
    }
};

var arr = [];
arr.push( ( function() {alert('A'); } ) );
arr.push( ( function() {alert('B'); } ) );
arr.push( ( function() {alert('C'); } ) );
arr.execute();
```

please keep in mind: it's not recommended to extend basical Javascript types in the way I did.

Comment: don't (ever) iterate arrays using the `for..in` syntax. Check this funky result : `Array.prototype.F = function(){alert('where did I came from?')};[].execute();`

Comment: If it is not recommended, why would you do it in your answer? Also, AFAIK it is usually not recommended to extend the base `Object` or any DOM Object, but the rest is fine.

Comment: it's only a lazy solution. you could derive a class from array, and extend it this way, but then you've to write `var arr = new MyArray()`

Comment: Extending `Array.prototype` is perfectly fine unless you have to deal with crappy code that uses `for..in` to iterate over arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you mean by "run when it been called", but since Arrays are Objects, you can store static information as object keys in the array:

```
var arr = ['foo','bar'];
arr.methods = {
   foo: function() { alert(this[0]); },
   bar: function() { alert(this[1]); },
};
arr.run = function() {
    for (var fn in this.methods) {
        this.methods[fn].call(this);
    }
};

​arr.run();​
```

You could also make this into a reusable function using prototypal inheritance, but you would need to embed the array inside it, since Arrays are not "subclassable" in javascript.

Comment: it's nearby the same solution like mine, but here you've alway to set arr.run for each instance. good solution, too

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function on the fly and store the reference in a variable:

```
var something = function() { alert("hello world"); };
```

And by extension in an array:

```
var something = [function() { alert("hello world"); }, 
                 function() { alert("hello world"); }, 
                 function() { alert("hello world"); }];
```

Which you may later call by using `something();` in the first example or `something[1]();` in the second for instance. Eval is absolutely not needed here, unless the actual body of the function comes from user input (god forbid :-) )

What and how to call it is left to the implementation, but it should be fairly trivial once you are aware of this.

Comment: You're not assigning closures to anything here, you're merely creating references to functions.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem In practical terms there's no difference, since the function can only be used with that specific reference anyway.

Comment: completely untrue mate. `someFunc = function(){ return null;}; var anotherVar = someFunc; anotherVar();` will work just fine. The key thing you're missing, though is: no references are enclosed nor exposed in your code. There is no _enclosing_ or _exposing_ going on, no scope is being preserved, so there is no _closure_ at all

Comment: Well yes, you can assign the *reference* to another variable and call it, but again speaking about practical terms I fail to see how does that make a difference compared to copying the function to another variable and call it (other than in memory). Also, a closure doesn't necesarily have to preserve a scope to be a closure.

Comment: Mahn, I think you need to read up about a couple of things: functions are objects in JS, so they're always passed by reference, never copied. Declaring a function the _"regular"_ way `function foo (){}` is essentially the same as `var foo = function(){}`, except for hoisting. You're just instantiating a function object. And AFAIK, the definition of a closure is this: _A "closure" is an expression (typically a function) that can have free variables together with an environment that binds those variables (that "closes" the expression)._ So you do need an _environment_ (AKA _scope_)

Comment: Why, yes, I know functions are objects in JS, but that is not relevant to what OP is asking. As for closure, I've seen the definition vary depending on who speaks, but you are probably right, I'll edit out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since everybody keeps guessing at what it is you're actually looking for, here's my .02:

```
var closures = (function(Global,undefined)
{
    var that = [];//return value
    that[0] = (function(some,vars, forClosure1)
    {
         return function()
         {
             console.log(some, vars,forClosure1);
         };
    })(values,of,closureArguments);//create all closures you need
    that.execAll = function (context,args)//the method to call them all (with arguments)
    {
        context = (context === undefined || context === Global ? that : context);
        args = args.length ? args : [];//make sure arguments has length property
        for (var i=0;i<that.length;i++)
        {
            if (typeof that[i] === 'function')
            {
                that[i].apply(context,args);
            }
        }
    };
    return that;//return closure array (with execAll method)
})(window);
```

Now, I've created an array of closures, that has its own method `execAll`, you can pass 2 arguments to this method: the first determines the context in which the closre functions of the array will be called, the second expects an array or arguments object to pass to each of these closure functions.
As it currently stands, the closures *cannot* be called in a global context using `execAll`. That's just for safety, but you never know, maybe you might want to call them in the global object's context.

All in all, I think this is what you're looking for, though I must admit: I'm struggeling to see how this code could be of any use, but maybe that's just me.
Anyway: good luck